# My footer won't stay at the bottom if the content gets too long

Tags: html, css, footer, absolute

So I have been looking around on the internet to find a solution in order to make the footer stay at the very bottom on the page regardless of the length of the content of the page. I have followed the CSS from tutorials, the footer is only at the bottom of the page if the content is not long enough, if the content is much longer, the page will get the scroll bar and the footer will get stuck in the middle of the page as you scroll down for more content. Below is my CSS and HTML.

```
body,html{
  background-color:#fff;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}


.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%; 
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

 .country-container {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:20%;
    width: 1024px;
    height:1300px;
    background:blue;
  }

 .container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:20%;
    width: 1024px;
    height:86px;
    max-height:300px;
    background:blue;
  }

#footer{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 max-height:900px;
 left:0px;
 color:#000099;
 background:#f2f2f2;
}


Now this is my html, the two absolute positioned divs and the footer are inside the wrapper which has position relative.
    <html>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="container">Container 1</div>
        <div class="country-container">Container 2</div>
        <div id="footer">Footer</div>

    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this above in Css code

```
<div style="width: 100%;height: auto;border:1px solid red;float:left;">
            <div style="width: 100%;height: auto;border:1px solid green;float:left;">

            </div>
            <div style="width: 100%;height: auto;border:5px solid Yellow;position: fixed;float:left;margin-top: 50%;">

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body,html{
  background-color:#fff;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}


.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%; 
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

 .country-container {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:20%;
    width: 1024px;
    height:1300px;
    background:blue;
  }

 .container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:20%;
    width: 1024px;
    height:86px;
    max-height:300px;
    background:blue;
  }

#footer{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 max-height:900px;
 left:0px;
 color:#000099;
 background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

        <div class="container">Container 1</div>
        <div class="country-container">Container 2</div>
        <div id="footer">Footer</div>

    </div>
```

change #footer to

```
position:fixed;
```

Comment: . I don't want it to be fixed. I want it to be dynamic and stay at the bottom and adjust to the length of the page content. Fixed doesn't not fix it.

Comment: @SemiM are u kidding me , you have "solution in order to make the footer stay at the very bottom on the page regardless of the length of the content of the page." in question , what actually you think it mean. Now you dont want it be in very bottom

Comment: FIXED will make it stay at its position no matter what. IF I have content that requires the page to scroll down for more content, I want the footer to still stay at the very bottom.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH !! Did the rules change then ?  Because I swear, all the tutorials I saw online to have a sticky footer show that you need to include it inside the wrapper with position relative, and then add the footer with position absolute and bottom 0px

Comment: Like this one ... http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: How is my CSS different from the link above with the footer with position absolute ?  I am curious.

Comment: Ok will do .. but why is the CSS from the link of the tutorial above not working ?  it's like my original CSS ?

Comment: @SemiM You might also want to add a margin at the bottom of the last `<div>` in the wrapper; otherwise stuff at the very bottom will get cut off by the footer.

Comment: Will do thank you .. but can you explain why mine was not working with absolute ?  It's code from the tutorials ? I am curious why

Comment: @SemiM why would you call that tutorial code and your code being same , your code is whole mess lot of relative-absolute relations all over for no reason. lof of offsets here and there.

Comment: You're wrong about that, I'm sorry. My code only has the wrapper that has the relative position and the inner divs have absolute positions just like instructed by the tutorials. There is something just not making sense.

Comment: Nirpendra Patel, your code partially hides some content even though I added a spacer after the last div. Thanks for helping but it doesn't really work either.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this css and see fiddle link:

```
body,html{
  background-color:#fff;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}


.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%; 
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

 .country-container {
  background: #0000ff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 1300px;
  left: 20%;
  position: relative;
  width: 1024px;
}

.container {
  background: #0000ff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 86px;
  left: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  max-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 1024px;
}

#footer {
  background: #f2f2f2 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #000099;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 900px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tn30t1k7/2/

Otherwise you can reffer this link:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: What was wrong with my CSS then ?  I followed the tutorials online that instructed to make the footer absolutely positioned within the wrapper that has a relative position with min-height:100%... where did I go wrong ?

Comment: very small changes for try , replease position both of class .wrapper  and .country-container remove absolute and put relative position.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
    <section class="wrapper">
        <main class="content">
            content
        </main>

        <footer class="footer">
            footer
        </footer>
    </section>
</body>


html {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0 0 60px 0;
}

/* don't do that */
/*  .wrapper {
  position: relative;
}  */

.content {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  /* height: 700px; */
}

footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

How about this https://jsfiddle.net/zkto8o88/2/.

.footer class will search for the nearest parent with relative position which in this case is html tag.

If the .wrapper class would have the position relative property then it would not work.

Comment: but wrapper is the nearest parent with the position relative in my question .. how was that not working then ?

Comment: Being positioned absolute they can't dictate their parent height. So that min-height on .wrapper is useless. Just remove the absolute position from containers. Give them margin bottom if you want space between. It's a probleme how you are trying to create your html.

Comment: Victor, THANK YOU SO MUCH! I am going to try your example and see how that works. So basically the absolute position of the child containers didn't respect the relative position of the wrapper parent. In order for them to respect it, the absolute position needed to be removed from container. I'll try this

Comment: there's an issue though with my example you fixed. If I choose to make the footer's height greater than 100px. let's say 600px, part of the second container (country-container will be overlapped with the big footer instead of the footer not overlapping the second container if the height is greater. My site may need a larger footer with lots of links and I'd still want to two big content container not to be overlapped. How would you fix that in case you make the footer height 500px with my example you fixed ?